# Is curl enabled in heroku and if not then how can I enable it?

Tags: facebook, curl, heroku, facebook-php-sdk

I am using heroku to deploy my php facebook application. facebook sdk uses curl. Is curl enabled in heroku? If not then how can I enable curl there?

Comment: so you did not even try it before asking?

Comment: I have been trying to use the facebook-php-sdk for last 3 days.

Comment: then tell us EXACTLY what you have tried so far. it should be pretty easy to find out if curl is enabled on a server, with phpinfo, for example.

Comment: also, you should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: it is a simple question. do u know?

Comment: It is a simple question, and had you searched for "heroku php curl" and followed the very first hit, you would have found this, which answers your question: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#extensions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cURL is included for Heroku PHP support

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#extensions